# Must this function necessarily be decreasing?

Tags: calculus, functional-equations, monotone-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a strictly monotone function satisfying
$$
f(f(x)) - f(x) = e^x + x - 1 
$$
for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

**Can we conclude that $f$ must be decreasing?**

(I don't know if there is such a function $f$, so the claim might be vacuously true.) We know that $f$ must be injective and $f(0) = 0$, so either $f(x) < 0$ for negative $x$ and $f(x) > 0$ for positive $x$ or the other way around. If we replaced $e^x + x - 1$ by $x$ then the answer would be no, as then $f(x) = \phi x$ would be an increasing solution, where $\phi$ is the golden ratio. Therefore a proof would have to use some property of $e^x + x - 1$ that $x$ alone doesn't have, if the claim is even true.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Since $g(x):=e^x + x -1$ is bijective, increasing and continuous, did you know that this is enough to imply there is a *unique* strictly increasing function $f$ satisfying $f(f(x)) = e^x + x-1 ?$ According to this answer, at least: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4703942/29156 . I'm not sure to what extent this helps answer your question though...

Comment: I think both will work. Unlikely it is analytic at the origin, still a  formal power series  for increasing begins  $2  x + (1/10)  x^2  + (19/1350)  x^3   + (49/45900)  x^4$

Comment: where did you get the question?

Comment: @WillJagy from [here](https://old.reddit.com/r/learnmath/comments/16jlw3w/if_f_is_a_strictly_monotonic_function_and_ffxfxex/)

Comment: alright;  as one of the people there mentions, the derivative at the origin is either $-1$  or $2.$  From what I can see, both work.  Suggest you find a few more terms in the power series I started,  also the other series $-x + more.$  Not sure about analyticity at the origin.   Well, see  my MO  question and answer  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/45608/formal-power-series-convergence/